# Windows 8 MouseEvents Buffering

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, mouseevent

We have a C#/DirectX application that is using a winform control events (mouseup,mousemove,paint,etc.)

When executed on a Windows 7 machine, whenever these events are triggered they are with the most recent values available (last mouse position). Therefore as soon as the mouse stop moving I get the final frame rendered on screen.

On a windows 8 machine it is as if these events are buffered, so if the UI thread is somewhat busy and I move the mouse frantically these events keeps on coming long after I stop moving the mouse.

Why is the behavior different on both system? And how can I make it identical? (it's also possible that its not related to the version of Windows but thats the only notable difference that come to mind thus far).

I know I can probably handle the "buffering"/"discarding" of events on my side but if it is related to the OS maybe there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2908279

Comment: I can't install the fix, apparently it is part of the December rollup which is allready installed (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2903939) and even with the registry manual fix it did not solved the problem.